# If two sprites are in different CCPhysicsNodes, can collision happen?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, game-physics, spritebuilder

If two sprites are in different CCPhysicsNodes, can collision happen? I had both sprites in the same PhysicsNode but one should be affected by gravity and second should not, that's why I created another  PhysicsNode and placed second sprite there. Since that moment collision doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong? (I am using cocos2d + SpriteBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

> If two sprites are in different CCPhysicsNodes, can collision happen?

No. The two sprites exist in two different instances of the physics world, they will not interact with each other.

> one should be affected by gravity and second should not

That's what the `Affected by gravity` checkbox in SpriteBuilder is for:

[image]

Comment: Hm,when I set all sprites to be static(and "affected by gravity" is unchecked), one sprite is still affected. Why?

Comment: Static bodies are never affected by gravity, only Dynamic bodies (I just happened to have this particular image at hand). If one of the physics nodes is falling, it must be dynamic and affected by gravity unchecked. Perhaps you simply have two sprites at the same location, if you use copy & paste this can sometimes happen. Also for Sub File nodes consider that you'll have to check the referenced CCB file and the node(s) it contains, because the Sub File node itself has no physics properties respectively ignores them.